# MinGW and CLang stop working?

Tags: c++, crash, mingw, clang

Both Clang and MinGW have stopped working. With MinGW, the programs I build crash, and Clang doesn't even let me compile. I have found what causes this running the GNU debugger on my app. Gtk#, which I recently installed, adds its own bin folder to my PATH, and this folder also has a libstdc++-6.dll. I think the compilers are looking at this DLL rather than the correct one in their own bin folder (which is also in PATH, but Gtk# must have "priority" or something). How can I prevent this collision?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalled both mingw and clang and reinstalling them?

Comment: Yes... Both were reinstalled and nothing happened.